# Xamarin forms check if keyboard is open or not

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keyboard-events

Is there any way to check if keyboard is open or not in Xamarin Forms? Are there any events getting fired when the keyboard opens or closes? If so, where can I find an example of it?

Answer (score 20):

I don't believe that there's a `Xamarin.Forms` way of doing it. Anyway, for the different platforms (at least Android and iOS) there is a way to achieve what you want.

## Android

Under android there is `InputMethodManager` class. You can obtain it from your activity

```
var inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
```

Now you can check if the keyboard is shown with

```
var keyboardIsShown = inputMethodManager.IsAcceptingText;
```

According to [this article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1172935/Detecting-Software-Keyboard-Events-in-Xamarin-Andr) you can use a class derived from `IOnGlobalLayoutListener` to listen to global layout events. When this event has fired, you can use the code above to check, if the layout has been changed due to the keyboard popping up.

## iOS

Under iOS you may use `UIKeyboard` class which allows you to observe the `DidShowNotification` (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification/)).

```
notification = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveDidShow ((sender, args) => {
    Debug.WriteLine("Keyboard is shown.");
    // whatever
});
```

similarly you can observe `DidHideNotification` (and some others - see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIKeyboard/)).

## Xamarin.Forms

To implement the keyboard-notification in your Xamarin.Forms the easiest way will be to implement platform dependencies which are resolved with the `DependencyService`. To do this, you'll first have to introduce an interface for the platform service.

```
public interface IKeyboardService
{
  event EventHandler KeyboardIsShown;
  event EventHandler KeyboardIsHidden;
}
```

In your platform specific projects you'll have to implement the functionality in a platform specific way. See the following code section for iOS implementation

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Your.iOS.Namespace.KeyboardService))]

namespace Your.iOS.Namespace
{
  public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
  {
    public event EventHandler KeyboardIsShown;
    public event EventHandler KeyboardIsHidden;

    public KeyboardService()
    {
      SubscribeEvents();
    }

    private void SubscribeEvents()
    {
      UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveDidShow(OnKeyboardDidShow);
      UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveDidHode(OnKeyboardDidHide);
    }

    private void OnKeyboardDidShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      KeyboardIsShown?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void OnKeyboardDidHide(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      KeyboardIsHidden?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}
```

The `Xamarin.Forms.Dependency` makes the class visible to the `DependencyService`. See the following code for Android implementation

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Your.Android.Namespace.KeyboardService))]

namespace Your.Android.Namespace
{
  public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
  {
    public event EventHandler KeyboardIsShown;
    public event EventHandler KeyboardIsHidden;

    private InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;

    private bool wasShown = false;

    public KeyboardService()
    {
      GetInputMethodManager();
      SubscribeEvents();
    }

    public void OnGlobalLayout(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      GetInputMethodManager();
      if(!wasShown && IsCurrentlyShown())
      {
        KeyboardIsShown?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        wasShown = true;
      }
      else if(wasShown && !IsCurrentlyShown())
      {
        KeyboardIsHidden?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        wasShown = false;
      }
    }

    private bool IsCurrentlyShown()
    {
      return inputMethodManager.IsAcceptingText;
    }

    private void GetInputMethodManager()
    {
      if (inputMethodManager == null || inputMethodManager.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
      }
    }

    private void SubscribeEvents()
    {
      ((Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context).Window.DecorView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += this.OnGlobalLayout;
    }
  }
}
```

In your Xamarin.Forms app you can now obtain an instance of the correct implementation of `IKeyboardService` with

```
var keyboardService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardService>();
```

Comment: Im new to xamarin forms.Can it be implemented in xamarin forms?Is there any example? @Paul

Comment: You could implement it in platform specific classes, which are retrieved by the `DependencyService` - see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) — if I find the time I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.It works when input receives focus and when I tap outside the input field.However it does not work when I press the hardware back button to hide the keyboard.Is there any way I can handle this case? @Paul

Comment: @Debasish I'm sorry, I've not worked with it, but just scraped the information from the web. I think you'll have to google a bit for `IOnGlobalLayoutListener` and back button :)

Comment: @mikkylekyle Did Alen Tomas answer help you?

Comment: i have a problem in this line  (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);

Comment: This doesn't work anymore 2021

Comment: The Android method does not work if the user hides the keyboard using the keyboard's down arrow. Anyone has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Forms in ANDROID CODE change

```
(InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
```

with

```
 (InputMethodManager)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
```

Comment: 2021 - Definitely does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
var inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
```

To:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)((Activity)Android.App.Application.Context).GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define interface for the platform service:

```
public interface IKeyboardService
{
    event EventHandler KeyboardIsShown;
    event EventHandler KeyboardIsHidden;
}
```

For Android:

Step 1. Add an Instance static variable into MainActivity.cs.

```
public static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    Instance = this;
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Step 2. Implement IKeyboardService in Android.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(KeyboardService))]
namespace App5.Droid
{
    public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
    {
        public event EventHandler KeyboardIsShown;
        public event EventHandler KeyboardIsHidden;

        private InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;

        private bool wasShown = false;

        public KeyboardService()
        {
            GetInputMethodManager();
            SubscribeEvents();
        }

        public void OnGlobalLayout(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            GetInputMethodManager();
            if (!wasShown && IsCurrentlyShown())
            {
                KeyboardIsShown?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                wasShown = true;
            }
            else if (wasShown && !IsCurrentlyShown())
            {
                KeyboardIsHidden?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                wasShown = false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsCurrentlyShown()
        {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            var view = MainActivity.Instance.Window.DecorView;
            view.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int screenHeight = view.RootView.Height;
            int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.Bottom);
            if (heightDifference > 200)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }
        }

        private void GetInputMethodManager()
        {
            if (inputMethodManager == null || inputMethodManager.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)MainActivity.Instance.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            }
        }

        private void SubscribeEvents()
        {
            MainActivity.Instance.Window.DecorView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += this.OnGlobalLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

For iOS, you could implement IKeyboardService as the following code:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(KeyboardService))]
namespace App5.iOS
{
    public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
    {
        public event EventHandler KeyboardIsShown;
        public event EventHandler KeyboardIsHidden;

        public KeyboardService()
        {
            SubscribeEvents();
        }

        private void SubscribeEvents()
        {
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveDidShow(OnKeyboardDidShow);
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveDidHide(OnKeyboardDidHide);
        }

        private void OnKeyboardDidShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KeyboardIsShown?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void OnKeyboardDidHide(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KeyboardIsHidden?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you could invoke this service to detect keybord show/hide event in Xamarin.Forms.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var keybordservice = DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardService>();
    keybordservice.KeyboardIsShown += (s, e) =>
    {
        test_icon.IsVisible = false;
    };
    keybordservice.KeyboardIsHidden += (s, e) =>
    {
        test_icon.IsVisible = true;
    };
}
// in my testing, I used an image as icon for test.
<Image x:Name="test_icon" Source="icon_about.png"/>
```