# How move the scroll only when there are the keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms

I used this function to move my scroll, but this function is activated when I don't have a keyboard, I only want to use it when there is a keyboard, how can I solve this?

```
<Entry    Placeholder="entry" Focused="EntryKeyboardHandle_Focused"

void EntryKeyboardHandle_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                    await MainScroll.ScrollToAsync(0, 100, true);
            });
        }
```

I found this thread [Xamarin forms check if keyboard is open or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360257/xamarin-forms-check-if-keyboard-is-open-or-not)

I have my entry with name "`Entry`" and in my code behind `Entry.Focused += keyboardService.KeyboardIsShown;` but I get this error.

> The event 'IKeyboardService.KeyboardIsShown' can only appear on the
>   left hand side of += or -=

Comment: There is already a thread with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360257/xamarin-forms-check-if-keyboard-is-open-or-not]

Comment: @Alen.Toma but how can i use that var keyboardService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardService>();  ?

Comment: the thread already tell you how, you create two classes for IOS and android called `KeyboardService` Then you use them with `DependencyService`.

Comment: @Alen.Toma thanks, but i get error, cannot find the interface

Comment: What is the error

Comment: @Alen.Toma i edited my question see please

Answer (score 1):

ok accourding to the thread that you found you could try this code.

in the contructor add this code

```
private bool _keyboardIsOn;

cto(){
 // Initio
 keyboardService.KeyboardIsShown += (sender, e){ _keyboardIsOn = true; }
 keyboardService.KeyboardIsHidden += (sender, e){ _keyboardIsOn = false; }
}
```

No you could check if `_keyboardIsOn` and add your coditions.

Comment: @mikkylekyle So Alen's reply solved your problem? if yes, please remember to mark his reply as answer, thanks.